# DownloadString Path error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, downloadstring

I'm using the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet in PowerShell to load modules.

The following code works as intended.

```
$url="http://pastebin.com/raw/FuxtpN69"

IEX (New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString($url)
```

But when I try using variables to split the domain and the page.

```
$u="http://pastebin.com"
$rl="/raw/FuxtpN69"

$url="$u$rl"

IEX (New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString($url)
```

I get the following path error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."
At line:8 char:53
+ IEX (New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString <<<< ($url)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me. Which PowerShell Version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.

Comment: I even can run this with version 2. Can you try to copy paste your example and try it?

Comment: The first example is working the one bellow isn't.
`$u="http://pastebin.com"
$rl="/raw/FuxtpN69"

$url="$u$rl"

IEX (New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadString($url)
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running PowerShell as a different account (for example an administrator).

Maybe that account's proxy settings are different that your normal account's?

See the credentials part first,

```
$webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
```

Then, Try setting

```
$client.Proxy = $null
```

before downloading and see if it helps.

Comment: The first example works fine, so I don't think its a proxy problem.

Comment: @BobBackers: added the webclient cred part .

Comment: @BobBackers: Its pretty interesting. Can you do one thing. Could you please invoke it locally in that server and see if you are able to download it? Probably we can narrow down the issue then . And run with admin in that.